# why should we merge entity prior to deleting in jpa/hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

why should we merge entity prior to removing it?
which of these efficient?

```
public void removeStudent(int i){
    Student studentD = entityManager.find(Student.class, i);
    tx.begin();
    entityManager.remove(studentD);
    tx.commit();
}

public void removeStudent(Student student){
    Student studentD = entityManager.merge(student);
    entityManager.remove(studentD);
}
```

Comment: Why would YOU merge prior to deleting? Only thing you need to delete is a "managed" object, so merging in some changes prior to deleting is pointless ... utterly pointless

Answer (score 0):

```
public void removeStudent(int i){
    Student studentD = entityManager.find(Student.class, i);
    tx.begin();
    entityManager.remove(studentD);
    tx.commit();
}
```

This code defeats the purpose of using transactions at all, don't **ever** use it. The call to `EntityManager.find` should be within the transaction scope, to ensure that you don't try to remove an entity that does not exist anymore.

If you need a reference to an entity for the sole purpose of removing it, use `EntityManager.getReference` instead of `EntityManager.find`.